# After new brake rotor installation, white smoke come out of brake system

Tags: brakes, brake-rotor

I installed new rotors and serviced my front brakes.

I sprayed both sides of the new rotors with brake cleaner.

I lubricated the caliper pins with [this brake lubricant](http://amzn.com/B005RNEH5O). I added the lubricant to the back of the pads as well.

After a street test, I tested the new brake service in a highway - 70 mph, and keep using brakes. The new front brake setup works well, smooth and quite. However, I noticed below problem?

After I tested the new rotor installation in the highway, I noticed white smoke comes out of the front wheels. The brake system works great and quite. Just white smoke. I waited for rotors to cool down. Then I did another highway test. I got less white smoke at the second test.

I guess the smoke is due to rotors are getting very hot and rust protective chemicals in them start to burn.

Since there is white smoke, did I use the right lubricant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its all down to the silicone paste. For brakes you would normally used copperslip. A copper based anti seize paste. It has a much higher tolerance for heat. I would remove the pads and use the correct compound rather than the silicone stuff. Inspect the pads for damage or the silicone getting on to the friction material.

Something like this [http://www.amazon.com/Permatex-09128-Copper-Anti-Seize-Lubricant/dp/B000HBM8HU/ref=sr_1_1?s=automotive&ie=UTF8&qid=1464075230&sr=1-1&keywords=copper+anti+seize](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000HBM8HU) is what I have always used on the backs of pads and the mating surface between the wheel and hub.  Be careful to not get it on braking surfaces

Comment: I am confused now. The 3M silicon plate brand is known for brake lubricant. I saw using them on many youtube tube brake videos.  on the container, it says lubricating brake parts. How could be so dangerously wrong?

Comment: That silicon paste is used for metal-rubber interfaces, not metal-metal. Use copperslip on the back of the pads.

Comment: @Pete and Mauro , I can't find copperslip, but is this the correct lubricant for metal to metal? http://amzn.com/B000HBNV6W

Answer (score 0):

That'll work metal to metal - but be careful that you don't get it on any rubber, as the rubber may swell (depends on the type of rubber, of course, but I'd play safe)